# Android Text to speech conversion

Tags: android

I am trying to write a java code for an android application which would convert my text to speech but i am getting an error in makeText method of Toast. I am new to android so please help me. The error which i am getting is

**The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (TexttoSpeech, String, 
 int)**

Here is my code

```
package com.example.messagereader;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TexttoSpeech {


    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private void speakOut()
{

    String num = null;
    String mes = null;
    String text ="Message From "+num+"Message Body :"+mes;
    if (text.length() == 0)
    {
        tts.speak("You haven't typed text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                null);
    }
    else
    {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
public void onInit(int status)
{
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(TexttoSpeech.this, "Language not Supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TTS Initilization Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }
}


}
```

Comment: You are passing an instance of `TexttoSpeech` instead of the context the toast is from. Replace `TexttoSpeech.this` in makeText with a correct context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass to your TexttoSpeech a Context from your activity. In your code `this` is a referene to `TexttoSpeech`, and Toast.makeText requires reference to Context as for its first argument. Activity class derives from Context, so you can pass to your class a `this` from your Activity.

[edit]

For showing Toast-s you can also you application Context, this means you can also show toasts from Services. To get application Context, call getApplicationContext on Context reference.